# Как сделать такой скрипт?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Ко мне приходит массив от сервера, вот такого вида: 
`Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]`

Вот таким запросом:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({id: param})
})
.then(function (response) {
     return response.json()
})
.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data); 
})
```

И есть на странице такой div:
`<div class="qqq"></div>`

Как мне каждый элемент добавить в `div.qqq` в виде ссылки, что-то вроде такого: `<a href="элемент_массива">элемент_массива</a>`.

Как сделать такое? подскажите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.then(function (data) {
  var parent = document.querySelector("div.qqq");
  data.forEach(function(el, index) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", el.field);
    a.innerText = el.field;
    parent.appendChild(a);
  });
})
```

Comment: Все, все) Спасибо) я разобрался)